# how can we get the actual text width in pixel of Spark TextInput?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, textinput

as textWidth property is no more accessible in spark textinput how we can get that property ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating Text Width In ActionScript And Flex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916919/calculating-text-width-in-actionscript-and-flex)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in spark there's something called `TextLineMetrics`

you can do it like this

```
var tm:TextLineMetrics = label.measureText( name );
var width:int = tm.width;
```

here's an example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.controls.Text;

        protected function cmdDoAction_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var tm:TextLineMetrics = cmdDoAction.measureText(cmdDoAction.label);
            var _width:int = tm.width;

            Alert.show(_width.toString());
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<s:Button id="cmdDoAction"
          label="Kensodev"
          click="cmdDoAction_clickHandler(event)"/>
    </s:Application>
```

This will give you the actual width

Comment: can we get length of text when, text is assigned to textinput control ?

Comment: Should not work for Spark text components according to docs: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#measureText()